# Chess book reviews

Tags: books

What are some of the useful chess book review websites or YouTube channels out there? Or even people with chess blogs or Youtube channels which occasionally post book reviews.

Answer (score 4):

The two web chess review sites I'm familiar with are [John Watson's reviews for TWIC](http://theweekinchess.com/john-watson-reviews) (The Week in Chess) and the book review section of [Grand Master Square](http://www.gmsquare.com/Reviews/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

The [Perpetual Chess Podcast](https://www.perpetualchesspod.com/) has an entire [Book Review Series](https://www.perpetualchesspod.com/recaptured) with an organized listing of books reviewed.

Coverage includes over 30 books, including a wide variety of book types (tournament books, game collections, tactics, strategy, improvement).

Here's a partial list:
[image: Partial list]

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Silman's website contains many chess book reviews:

https://www.jeremysilman.com/